# Binding to Arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, macos, cocoa-bindings

I have a document based app in OSX and am trying to bind an array in my `NSDocument` subclass with my `NSViewController` subclass. In both classes, I have created empty arrays of a custom object

```
var maps = [Map]()
```

After the `NSDocument`instantiates the view controller, and after the view controller has added a `Map` object to the `maps` array, I am trying to bind the two arrays together.  I am attempting to do this:

```
maps.bind("maps", toObject: "Document", withKeyPath: "myMaps", options: nil)
```

But I get an error

> `([Map])` does not have a member named `bind`

The documentation says that `NSKeyValueBindingCreation` is an informal protocol of `NSObject` which the `Map` object is subclassed from.  Not sure why the binding isn't working.

Thanks,

GW

Comment: Guessing now...`Map` inherits from `NSObject` so you should be able to call `bind` on an instance of a `Map` object. But in your code you are trying to call `bind` on an `Array` of `Map` objects. Meaning that it is not a `Map` object but an `Array` you are calling `bind` on. Could that be it?

Comment: The first parameter binding is the key path for a property of the receiver previously exposed using the exposeBinding: method. NSArray doesn't expose binding maps so this isn't going to work. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ultimately I am trying to find a way to send my array of Maps to the subclass of NSDocument so I can save, and conversely to open a file and send the data from the array to my view controller.

Is there a different way that I can send data from a view controller all the way up the chain to the document for saving?

Comment: Search stackoverflow for 'NSDocument NSViewController'.